# Half-width Katakana becomes garbled/not readable when outputting as CSV file

Tags: vb.net

I am outputing a CSV file with a one half-width japanese katakana value by SJIS encoding. But upon opening the file, text becomes garbled or not readable and encoding did not become SJIS([Not Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzvJ3.png)) even though I set it as SJIS before saving the file. But, when I did not transform it to half-width character. The result was okay.[Good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdtBN.png)

This is my code for writing file:

```
For Each ikey As Integer In dicHDO.Keys
strLine = GetOutputData(dicHDO(ikey)) + vbCrLf

'CSVファイル書込に使うEncoding
Dim enc As System.Text.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(932)

'書き込むファイルを開く
Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = New System.IO.StreamWriter(strFileName, True, enc)
sw.Write(strLine)

'閉じる
If sw IsNot Nothing Then
    sw.Close()
End If

Next

Private Function GetOutputData(tmpHDO() As String) As String
Dim st As String = ""

Try
    For i = 0 To tmpHDO.Count - 1
        If st = "" Then
            st = tmpHDO(i)
        Else
            st = st + "," + tmpHDO(i)
        End If
    Next

    Return st

Catch ex As Exception
    Throw ex
End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Missing the link to the imgae?  Better still, edit the question and append in in the code generating your file code

Comment: @Hursey Hi, already edited my post. I'm sorry this is my first time to post here. Anyways, Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `Encoding.UTF8` instead? So the System can more easily find a fall-back Font to represent those symbols. Btw, you should also show what `GetOutputData()` is doing, since this is what generates the output string.

Comment: hello @Jimi, already inserted the GetOutputData() function. Sorry, I already tried Encoding.UTF8, but the client wants SJIS type of encoding.

Comment: Yes, but there's no problem with that. I suggested to use UTF8 because that's the default encoding when saving files in Windows. A problem comes out when you use **two** different encodings to write to the same file. If the output file was already generated with *normal* means, you probably created an UTF8 (or Encoding.Default - the local encoding, depending on the method used to generate the file) encoded file. After that, you can only use that Encoding to write to that file. If you use another Encoding, you get garbled text -> here, you're **appending** text to a file.

Comment: okay @Jimi, thank you for your help.